# Search for a string in a string

Tags: sas

I have a data set which looks like the following, but containing thousands of rows.

```
Firstname   Lastname        Emailaddress
John        Smith           John.Smith@mail.com
Anna        Blake           Anna.Blake@mail.com
Susan       Peterson        1962_Peterson_Susan@mail.com
David       Anderson        RandomEmail_1956@mail.com
```

I want to create a variable which tells me if the email address is containing the persons first or last name at all in disregard of position. If a match is found, the variable would return the value 1 and if no match is found it would return the value 0.

I have created the following logic which works for most cases.

```
Data CheckNames;

   Set MyDataSet;

LenFM = Length(FirstName);
LenLM = Length(LastName);

If Substr(EmailAddress,1,LenFM) = FirstName or Substr(EmailAddress,1,LenLM) = LastName then Match = 1;

Else Match = 0;
```

run;

This logic would return Match = 1 for the first two results and Match = 0 for the last two. However I would like it to return Match = 1 for the third observation as well because it contains the name of the person.

My question is if there is a SAS command that lets me loop through all the observations in the variables Firstname and Lastname that then scans if the names are found in the variable EmailAddress.

I have tried with `Find()` and `PrxMatch()` but they both seem to require hard coded values, making them inefficient for this purpose.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `FIND` and `PRXMATCH` would work fine, and have no such requirement of hardcoded values.  `FIND` works particularly well for this.  Add the modifier `t` to tell it to trim the spaces from the firstname/lastname variable (or use the `trim` function).

```
data MyDataSet;
  length firstname lastname emailaddress $50;
  input Firstname $  Lastname  $      Emailaddress $;
datalines;
John        Smith           John.Smith@mail.com
Anna        Blake           Anna.Blake@mail.com
Susan       Peterson        1962_Peterson_Susan@mail.com
David       Anderson        RandomEmail_1956@mail.com
;;;;
run;

Data CheckNames;
   Set MyDataSet;    
   Match = find(EmailAddress,Firstname,'t') | find(EmailAddress,LastName,'t');
run;
```

I use `|` there to `OR` the two find functions' values together, but you can do it more explicitly if you prefer.